# Размер блоков под размер экрана

Tags: html, css

Здравствуйте! У меня есть блок на сайте, вот его код

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="655">
  <tbody><tr>
    <td class="top" background="/images/bgtop.jpg" height="39"><div style="padding:5px 0px 5px 15px"><h3><b>Ваши письма</b></h3></div></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="background-position:bottom" align="center" background="/images/bgbot.jpg"><div style="padding:15px 15px 25px 15px">
      <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="90%">
        <tbody><tr>
          <div id="progressbar"></div>
        </tr>
      </tbody></table>
    </div></td>
  </tr>
</tbody></table>
```

Как сделать что бы размеры были в процентах, что бы этот блок настраивался под размер экрана.

Answer (score 1):

Нужно блокам задавать размеры в процентах(%) а не в пикселях(px)

Comment: Как это сделать?) Я просто новичок в этом...

Answer (score 1):

`width="655"` Поменяйте на `width="75%"`, где 75% - это размер 3/4 от размера родителя. В вашем случае думаю родитель <body>

Comment: Все равно. У меня на компьютере нормально показывает, а захожу с планшета (размер экрана 10'1 дюйма)блоки нормально, но остальное смазывается...